# Unit Tests for Database Abstraction Layer

Tags: database, unit-testing, jquery

I previously asked [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197554/suitable-algorithm-for-joining-records-from-multiple-databases) question about creating an algorithm for joining records from multiple databases, and since then, I have built a rudimentary version of it (which doesn't allow for inter database table associations to keep it simple for the moment), and now I am trying to test it. So far, I have tested doing joins, custom columns, where and having clauses, order by's, and limits, and they seem to all work perfectly. But, most of my applications that do database queries are quite simple, with just a few joins, a couple of custom columns, and a few other bits and pieces of information, so I was wondering if there was a nice series of really complex queries i could pass through it to ensure that it can really do everything that would be needed by 99% of applications? I know its a bit broad, but even just a handful of complicated queries would be fantastic to test it out.

Comment: What kind of complexity are you looking for? Or are you looking for tests that stress the limits of your implementation in terms of number of joins and where clauses? The latter are usually not unit tests.

Comment: Preferably, something containing as many different types of queries that could conceivably be used. It's not so much a stress test, but to ensure that it can perform those queries

Comment: You might look at the tests used by the open source database implementations (e.g. sqlite3 or MySQL)

Comment: I have been having a look, but I can't find any resources to that. Do you know of any resources?